# How do I use the Microsoft VSTO interfaces?

Tags: c#, interface, vsto, ms-office

I would like to create an addin for microsoft outlook, and am using the visual studio tools to do so.

However I am really struggling to get my head around the use of interfaces within the VSTO environment - the resources on MSDN show many useful looking interfaces, but I am unsure how to use these interfaces to access data. For example I am trying to add a new folder into an IMAP account but am finding it very difficult to work out how to get outlook to do so.

Can anyone recommend any good resources for learning how to use VSTO (I have VSTO for dummies, but it doesn't cover the level of detail I need, I have been using MSDN, but I have found it doesnt offer much information on how to use the interfaces etc.)

Comment: VSTO is pretty much not backwards compatible and changes all the time.  I recommend you take it one step at a time.  Define a particular problem and research it on google or ask about it on SO/MSDN.  I've used it on and off for several years and still just make one-offs because of this.  Understanding the design is gonna be a big whoopin and good luck if it doesn't just change.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking out the book by Eric Carter + Eric Lippert, "Visual Studio Tools for Office 2007: VSTO for Excel, Word, and Outlook". It covers VSTO 2007, and not 2010, but it gives a solid overview of the object model for each of the 3 major Office applications, and has some good explanations on the interfaces.

[http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Studio-Tools-Office-2007/dp/0321533216](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321533216)